# How to save PCA summary?

Tags: r, pca

I have used `prcomp` function to perform PCA of my data. I can save other data like, center, scale, score, rotation in csv using `write.csv` function but I don't know how to save PCA summary.

Data I used

```
structure(list(Location = c("Luoyuan Bay", "Luoyuan Bay", "Luoyuan Bay", 
"Luoyuan Bay", "Luoyuan Bay", "Luoyuan Bay", "Luoyuan Bay", "Luoyuan Bay", 
"Luoyuan Bay", "Luoyuan Bay", "Luoyuan Bay", "Luoyuan Bay", "Luoyuan Bay", 
"Luoyuan Bay", "Luoyuan Bay", "Luoyuan Bay", "Luoyuan Bay", "Luoyuan Bay", 
"Luoyuan Bay", "Luoyuan Bay", "Luoyuan Bay"), Serial = 32:52, 
    Station = c("NDDZ91", "NDDZ92", "NDDZ94", "NDDZ95", "NDDZ96", 
    "NDDZ97", "NDDZ98", "NDDZ99", "NDDZ103", "NDDZ105", "NDDZ106", 
    "NDDZ107", "NDDZ112", "NDDZ113", "NDDZ114", "NDDZ115", "NDDZ116", 
    "NDDZ117", "NDDZ119", "NDDZ122", "NDDZ123"), Longitude = c(119.6875, 
    119.6641667, 119.7163889, 119.7425, 119.69, 119.7719444, 
    119.6622222, 119.7544444, 119.6644444, 119.6875, 119.7369444, 
    119.7672222, 119.6583333, 119.6327778, 119.5991667, 119.6769444, 
    119.7019444, 119.7419444, 119.6216667, 119.6722222, 119.6408333
    ), Latitude = c(26.34944444, 26.35972222, 26.36, 26.36027778, 
    26.37583333, 26.38277778, 26.38638889, 26.39277778, 26.41055556, 
    26.41972222, 26.42833333, 26.42861111, 26.43361111, 26.44416667, 
    26.45, 26.45, 26.44805556, 26.44805556, 26.46638889, 26.47166667, 
    26.4775), Petrolium = c(20.26723856, 35.12860786, 38.00639611, 
    485.9158071, 6.801285888, 130.2613429, 26.41691724, 21.47363409, 
    75.24255785, 9.088017875, 17.83869051, 106.4365614, 367.7372615, 
    26.95847112, 42.01753212, 17.56582294, 72.00256098, 382.5705508, 
    150.0004825, 452.8679126, 61.51137016), Sulfide = c(15.16, 
    47.67, 30.23, 75.05, 10.51, 38.75, 21.64, 35.97, 122.53, 
    6.95, 58.52, 75.92, 92.23, 10.85, 72.1, 28.46, 81.19, 195.59, 
    42.54, 277.4, 81.67), PAH = c(0.0479, 0.0638, 0.1312, 0.1293, 
    0.0589, 0.1032, 0.2725, 0.0712, 0.1173, 0.0703, 0.2097, 0.1261, 
    0.0685, 0.0796, 0.1353, 0.0354, 0.0323, 0.034, 0.0269, 0.0952, 
    0.0269), OCP = c(0.01071845, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.004247812, 0, 
    0, 0, 0.002020821, 0, 0.055799207, 0.003690873, 0.019063717, 
    0, 0.173323781, 0.010429405, 0, 0, 0.013486877, 0), PES = c(0, 
    44.15139004, 17.922209, 35.47228577, 0, 66.9289217, 11.62692114, 
    30.51552678, 57.2039725, 35.11363161, 49.43776022, 83.9088046, 
    0, 0, 45.56461801, 0, 0, 8.461490717, 29.69151766, 76.46222766, 
    34.05399385), Acrylic = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 30.51552678, 
    0, 0, 0, 41.9544023, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), PP = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 5.263920851, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 49.43776022, 0, 186.2662335, 
    248.4375, 0, 0, 0, 4.230745359, 0, 0, 0), Rayon = c(74.23500995, 
    58.86852005, 53.766627, 70.94457153, 26.31960425, 0, 69.76152682, 
    61.03105356, 114.407945, 70.22726323, 49.43776022, 41.9544023, 
    0, 0, 136.693854, 112.339267, 36.33232944, 16.92298143, 59.38303531, 
    305.8489106, 102.1619815)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-21L))
```

CODE I used for PCA

```
Mydata = read.csv("PCA_Luoyuan.csv")
head(Mydata)
pca = prcomp(Mydata[,6:13], scale. = TRUE)
summary(pca)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract `importance` from `summary(pca)`.

```
write.csv(summary(pca)$importance, 'temp.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

We could also use `write.table`

```
write.table(summary(pca)$importance, "temp.txt")
```